# Pintool- How can I traverse through all traces (even the ones that have already been executed once)?

Tags: intel-pin

I'm trying to count how many times a bbl is executed in the whole program run, but apparently, Trace_addinstrumentfunction skips traces that have already been executed once. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pin instrumentation works in two phases. The instrumentation phase is called when new code is encountered, and allows you to insert analysis callbacks. Analysis callbacks are called every time the code is encountered.

I strongly recommend reading the first bit of the pin manual to understand the difference between instrumentation and analysis functions.

Answer (score 0):

The instrumentation called allows you to insert the callbacks. In simpler terms, the function will have you put function calls before each instrument. You can define this instrument as either Instruction, Trace or Routine. Now, specific to your question, finding number of bbl is easy. Pin however follows a different definition of BBL. Finding the number of times a BBL(Per Pin's definition) is executed is easy. You can simply insert an Trace Instrumentation call and for every BBL increment a counter in the analysis call and you will get the BBL count.

If you want to go by the textbook definition of BBL(one entry one exit) which implies one BBL breaks at the BranchOrCall statement, insert a call using IsBranchOrCall API and increment the BBLcounter in the callback function.

I recommend trying both of them and figuring out the difference between the two definitions.